# Print out file structure on Unix

Tags: files, tree

Is there a way on unix to print out the file structure, like Bootstrap's getting started page?

```
bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

(from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included)

Is there a command to make it print out exactly like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look to tree command.

http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

For debian like distro :

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```